# Splunk ODBC error when using from Tableau

Tags: sql, database, tableau-api, splunk

I connected Tableau Desktop 10.5 successfully to my Splunk server, and I see all my saved searches. My data source is a join between Splunk and Denodo.

I can place dimensions from Denodo with no problem. However, when attempting to add one of the dimensions from the Splunk datasets, I'm getting the following error:

```
[Splunk][SplunkODBC] (40) Error with HTTP API, error code: Failed writing received data to disk/application
```

When pressing "Show Query", I see a weird one:

```
SELECT "test_table"."testfield" AS "X_testfield_binary__0", 
"test_table"."testfield" AS "testfield_(test_table)" 
FROM "test_table"
```

I've tried restarting Tableau, running it as admin, changing to extract or live. I have no problem with disk space. I'm not sure what's the problem, and googling it proved unsuccessful.

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix it?

(sorry about formatting; I'm on mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it

Instead of trying to JOIN Splunk and Denodo, I separated them to 2 different data sources and used **Data Blending** to link them based on the fields I joined on. Then, the queries were successful.